# plugins break after moving wp-content folder

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to move my wp-content folder to a different drive (from /var/www/html/ to /mnt/)
I tried creating a symlink from the wp-content to the new wp-content folder but that doesn't seem to work. 
I tried to use the following(I'm guessing this is where the problem lies?):

```
    //define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', '../../../../mnt/folder/wp-content');
    //define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://site/wp-content');
    //define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', '../../../../folder/content/plugins'); 
    //define('WP_PLUGIN_URL', 'https://site/wp-content/plugins');
    //define( 'PLUGINDIR', '../../../../mnt/folder/content/plugins');
```

It seemed to work, for the most part. But when I enable any plugins I get an MSQL warning saying there are too many connections. I get locked out of the admin dashboard but I can fix it by renaming the plugins folder.

Comment: WP doesn't support symlinks, and a lot of plugins hardcode the `wp-content` path which they shouldn't

Comment: @TomJNowell not true on support, WP core makes an attempt to resolve symlinks for plugins since 3.9, see `wp_register_plugin_realpath()`

Comment: Does symlink actually work, as in can you use file managed to observe directories and files appear in the linked to location?

Comment: @Rarst Yeah it works. Using the absolute links it shouldn't matter anyway though, right?